Linear Independence without Vandermonde Determinant
Let $n > 2$ be an integer, $X_1, \ldots,X_n$  be vectors in a vector space, and $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are nonzero, mutually different scalars.
I want to prove the following implication:
$$
\lambda_i X_1 + \lambda_i^2 X_2 + \cdots + \lambda_i^{n-1} X_{n-1} = 0, \quad \forall i = 1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \implies X_1 = \cdots = X_{n-1} = 0.
$$
I am considering using a Vandermonde determinant, but I want an explicit recurrent method.

Since these are linear equations in the $X_i$, we can prove it componentwise; let $X_{i,j}$ denote the $j$th component of $X_i$.
Consider the polynomial $$p_j(t) = X_{1,j} t + X_{2,j} t^2 + \cdots + X_{n-1,j} t^{n-1}.$$ If $p_j$ is not identically zero, then it has at most $n-1$ zeros (since $t - \lambda$ is a factor of $p_j(t)$ if $p_j(\lambda) = 0$, and $p_j(t)$ can only have at most $\deg(p_j) \le n-1$ linear factors). But we know that $p_j(0) = 0$ and $p_j(\lambda_i) = 0 \;(i = 1, \ldots, n-1)$, so it has at least $n$ distinct zeros; therefore $p_j$ must be identically zero and its coefficients $X_{i,j} \;(i = 1, \ldots, n-1)$ are zero. Since this works for all $j$, the vectors $X_i$ are all zero.

I see that you consider the vector space to be finite-dimensional, which is not necessary for the implication.

@yassine No, it doesn't need to be finite-dimensional - $j$ could index any (possibly infinite) basis. Alternatively, you could just consider the finite-dimensional subspace spanned by the $X_i$.

yes thanks, i see now what you mean.
